# Html Aglity Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am using visual studio 2013 and it has built in html agility pack and I have update it to but it is not showing me in library neither by using htmlagilitypack nor by adding references

Comment: I suggest you get where the DLL file is and add it as reference.

Comment: I have tried it but can't file the dll files in visual studio 2013

Answer (score 1):

The **HTML Agility Pack** is not part of Visual Studio 2013.

You can get it from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

Comment: You have downloaded it from where and how?